# ASP.NET exceptions in AWS Linux

Tags: asp.net, linux, docker, asp.net-core, amazon-ecs

When I run ASP.NET 5 in Windows, and it throws an exception, I can view the entry in the Windows Event Viewer. I have deployed my site in a Docker container to Amazon's ECS, so it's running in Linux now. Where should I look in Linux to similarly view such entries?

I am trying to troubleshoot an error when I communicate with RDS, but it only occurs when I'm looking at it Linux, not when I run the site in the Visual Studio debugger.

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: That's the problem. I wanted to view the entry so that I could determine what exception I'm receiving.

Comment: Is it possible to get console output on AWS? If yes, you can try setting the `DNX_TRACE` environment variable to 1 and get more details status. You can also share how you deploy because that might give some indications about what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the Docker log can be viewed with the following command

```
docker logs ad7629ef8bc | less
```

where `ad7629ef8bc` is your desired container ID. `less` redirects the output to a scrollable UI. To exit the UI, and return to the prompt simply press the `q` key. I also found a lot more documentation on `less` and other output options at http://linuxcommand.org/lts0060.php.

You can find a list of all Docker commands at `docker --help`.